# ArrayPlot - Question about ColorFunction and PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, color, legending

I have a noise image (8bit, gray scale): https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIgOk.png

The following code:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIgOk.png", "PNG"];

imageData = N@ImageData[image, "Byte"];

colTable = {Red, Green, Blue};

plot = ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

produces an `ArrayPlot`:

[image]

I have two questions:

1.
How can I change the vertical extension of the color legend, so that it as high as the plot is.

2.
The image contains only Byte values of 9,10,11:

```
Histogram[Flatten@imageData, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

How can I use my upper color table which only consist of 3 colors instead of smoothing in between?

Comment: Why not use `ColorRules` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of ideas here.  First, as J.M. commented above, you could use exact (Integer) values and [`ColorRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorRules.html):

```
imageData = ImageData[image, "Byte"];

ArrayPlot[imageData
 , ColorRules  -> Thread[{9, 10, 11} -> colTable]
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic
 , FrameTicks  -> All
 , ImageSize   -> Medium
]
```

[image]

That handily solves your legend size issue as well, at least for this case.

If that is not what you want you could use a color function like `colTable[[⌈3 #⌉]] &` to select the color you want.  The legend can easily be resized by hand (just click it and drag the corners of the orange frame that appears).

```
ArrayPlot[imageData
  , ColorFunction -> (colTable[[⌈3 #⌉]] &)
  , PlotLegends   -> Automatic
  , FrameTicks    -> All
  , ImageSize     -> Medium
]
```

---

Finally with [rcollyer's assistance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123240/121) I learned that we need to specify an explicit `AspectRatio` to get correct autosizing of the legend in this case:

```
ArrayPlot[imageData
  , ColorFunction -> (colTable[[⌈3 #⌉]] &)
  , PlotLegends   -> Placed[Automatic, Right]
  , FrameTicks    -> All
  , ImageSize     -> Medium
  , AspectRatio   -> 1/3
]
```

[image]

Incorporating an additional detail from the comments, we can set the range of the legend bar like this:

```
ArrayPlot[imageData
  , ColorFunction -> (colTable[[⌈3 #⌉]] &)
  , PlotLegends   -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {9, 12}}], Right]
  , FrameTicks    -> All
  , ImageSize     -> Medium
  , AspectRatio   -> 1/3
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great .. thanks.  Is it possible the red goes from 9 to 10, green from 10 to 11 and red from 11 to 12? Or everything can be shifted by -0.5 ... In your legend each color extends over about 0.6.

Comment: @mrz Good point.  Let me see what I can do about that.  Also, thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @mrz It looks like `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {9, 12}}]` will be the easiest way to achieve that.  This can be combined with `Placed`: `Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {9, 12}}], Right]`

Comment: Perfect ... that's it

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    plot = ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 2, LegendMarkerSize -> 125], 
  FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

with the effect:

[image]

or this:

```
     plot = ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
      PlotLegends ->Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 2, LegendMarkerSize -> 340], Below], 
FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

yielding the following

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Is there some way to *automatically* set the legend size or `LegendMarkerSize`?  I have been working on that for the last few minutes to no avail.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it is being automatically set, `ImageSize` is translated to `LegendMarkerSize`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not that I know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard the issue is the `AspectRatio` of the image is "funny", so the height is being taken into account as well as it should.

Comment: @rcollyer I am sorry, I don't know what you mean.  Alexei had to directly specify `LegendMarkerSize -> 125` or `LegendMarkerSize -> 340` to get the size right here.  I am wondering if there is something like `LegendMarkerSize -> Full` that will do this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `LegendMarkerSize -> Automatic` (the default) is supposed to pick up the `ImageSize`. But, `ArrayPlot` is producing something where the vertical and horizontal dimensions differ quite a bit, so the legend is much larger than it should be. You can trick it by setting an [`AspectRatio`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123240/52).

Comment: This is also a very good solution ...please excuse me but I can only for one answer

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think using `ColorRules` is the best option. But, in case you want to use `ColorFunction` (with the resulting `BarLegend`), I would suggest setting the `AspectRatio`, too, e.g.

```
ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, FrameTicks -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Or you could set it to `1`

```
ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, FrameTicks -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Although, I prefer `1/2`.

Comment: Oh, so *that's* how it is done.  What I was looking for: `ArrayPlot[imageData, ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], ImageSize -> Medium, FrameTicks -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]`